# Getting Cloudwatch EC2 server health monitoring into ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS account, and have several EC2 servers and an ElasticSearch domain set up to take the syslogs from these servers. However, in Cloudwatch and when investigating a specific server instance in the EC2 control panel, I see specific metrics and graphs for things like CPU, memory load, storage use, etc. Is there some way I can pipe this information into my ElasticSearch as well?

Answer (score 0):

Set up Logstash and use this plugin https://github.com/EagerELK/logstash-input-cloudwatch

Or go the other way and use AWS Logs agent to put your syslogs into Cloudwatch and stop using ElasticSearch